# How to stop mousedown event on reaching specific number in increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I break, kill or stop mousedown event when hits an specific benchmark?

For example in following code, I want to disable the Key and event when the `temp` hits `30`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var temp = 0;
  var to = null;
  var iv = null;

  $("#ClickMe").on("mousedown", function() {
    temp++;
    $("#Temp").html(temp);
    to = setTimeout(function() {
      iv = setInterval(function() {
        temp++;
        $("#Temp").html(temp);
      }, 75);
    }, 500);
  }).on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(to);
    clearInterval(iv);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 26px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ClickMe">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="Temp">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, complete answer, with code...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var temp = 0;
  var to = null;
  var iv = null;

  $("#ClickMe")
  .on("mousedown", function() {
    temp++;
    $("#Temp").html(temp);
    to = setTimeout(function() {
      iv = setInterval(moreClick, 75);
    }, 500);
  })
  .on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(to);
    clearInterval(iv);
    test_stopClick();
  });

  function moreClick() {
    $("#Temp").html(++temp);
    test_stopClick();
  }

  function test_stopClick() {
    if (temp >= 30 ) {
      clearTimeout(to);
      clearInterval(iv);
      $("#ClickMe")
      .off("mousedown mouseup mouseleave")
      .prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 26px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="ClickMe">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="Temp">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `if` statement, and then use jQuery's `.off()` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var temp = 0;
  var to = null;
  var iv = null;

  $("#ClickMe").on("mousedown", function() {
    if (temp < 30) {
      temp++;
      $("#Temp").html(temp);
      to = setTimeout(function() {
        iv = setInterval(function() {
          temp++;
          $("#Temp").html(temp);
        }, 75);
      }, 500);
    } else {
      $("#ClickMe").off("mousedown");
    }
  }).on("mouseup mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(to);
    clearInterval(iv);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 26px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ClickMe">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="Temp">0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jack but this is not stopping at 30

Comment: Yes it is - you can't make it go past 30. Is there something I haven't taken from your question that I need to put in my answer @Behseini?

Comment: but if you keep mouse down from 0 and continue it will not stop at 30 until you mouse up

Comment: That's because that's a different event.

Comment: Thanks bit I am looking for that event ! :-)